# How can I get background color of a layer in Photoshop?

Tags: background-color, layer, photoshop-cs3

I have a design in .psd format. It is using various layers and diffrent settings for opacity. I am using Photoshop CS3. How can I get background color of the layer. One way is to use in-build Color Palette utility but that doesn't suits me. I want a way by which I can get exact Brush that is used for the background. It may or may not have Gradients.

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: @skaffman, I have to read the Hexadecimal Code of color and use the same in my program.

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that this is programming related, but use the eye-dropper tool.

http://www.ehow.com/how_2193268_use-eye-dropper-tool-photoshop.html

Once the color is placed into your "foreground color" box, click the box and it will show you the color in RGB, Hex, and pretty much any other way you can display a color value.

Comment: I actually don't need Specific Color, I need Brush for same(Brush can contain multiple colors for gradient).

Comment: You're not being specific with your question. Why don't you post a photo of what you're trying to recreate??

Comment: check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmOU88nWbYU) video, hope helps in web development.